# Can the faded parts of a character in a receipt be restored?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, receipt

I have some files that contain some scanned receipts and I need to extract the text from them using OCR. Since the printed words in a receipt would fade out after some time, some words in the receipts are not clear and affect the OCR result.

Some examples of faded words:

[image: Faded 1]

[image: Faded 2]

Are there any ways to restore the faded parts so that I can improve the OCR result?

I have tried image thresholding and image smoothing in OpenCV but the results are not very satisfactory. Can the image be further processed?

Averaging then Gaussian Threshold
[image]

Gaussian Blur then Gaussian Threshold
[image]

Comment: basically: **no**. you'd have to hallucinate data into the picture that is just guesswork. with such low level operations it's impossible. you'd need at least a filter bank, possibly a CNN, both at the danger of hallucinating data into the picture that is wrong (btw, [xerox messed this up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBIG2#Disadvantages)). however, those approaches *implicitly* do OCR (find best match character and draw it over the picture), so a separate OCR step afterwards would be superfluous, a waste of time, pointless, you name it.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I also think that approach is like doing OCR. I have little knowledge on deep learning and machine learning, I wonder if it is possible to extend the unconnected segments and connect them based on their existing curvature.

Comment: I think that's more difficult than using a CNN and it will give you bad results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is not perfect and is not suitable for all characters (it is better to specify the range of characters, separate them and then try this method on separate characters). This is a basic idea; Maybe you can complete it. The final characters do not look like the original font and may just be more readable. This seems natural given the method chosen; Because of the damage to the characters, recognizing the name and type of the initial font is not easy.

```py
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load and resize image
im = cv2.imread(sys.path[0]+'/im.png')
H, W = im.shape[:2]
S = 4
im = cv2.resize(im, (W*S, H*S))

# Convert to binary
msk = im.copy()
msk = cv2.cvtColor(msk, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
msk = cv2.threshold(msk, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# Glue char blobs together
kernel1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11, 13))
kernel2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (4, 5))
msk = cv2.medianBlur(msk, 3)
msk = cv2.erode(msk, kernel1)
msk = cv2.erode(msk, kernel2)

# Skeletonization-like operation in OpenCV
thinned = cv2.ximgproc.thinning(~msk)

# Make final chars
msk = cv2.cvtColor(msk, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
thinned = cv2.cvtColor(thinned, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
thicked = cv2.erode(~thinned, np.ones((9, 15)))
thicked = cv2.medianBlur(thicked, 11)

# Save the output
top = np.hstack((im, ~msk))
btm = np.hstack((thinned, thicked))
cv2.imwrite(sys.path[0]+'/im_out.png', np.vstack((top, btm)))
```

[image]

---

More information about modules and their licenses:
[OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv), [NumPy](https://numpy.org/about/)

Note that the *thinning* algorithm is located in the *opencv_contrib* repository; Therefore, consider its license for use.

Comment: I got this error when running the code: AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'ximgproc'. I've installed opencv-contrib-python.

Comment: Yes I forgot to say you have to install the "contrib" package. Was the problem solved after installation?

Comment: I still get the same error after installation, does it require an old version?

Comment: I dont think so :) What is the error message?

Comment: Oh I found that I installed the library to another version of python