# How to improve the binarization of Text document ( Fill missing pixels of alphabets, reduce noise etc)

Tags: python, image, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision

**What (and how) can be done (like where exactly to plcae Erosion, Dialiation, Opening, Closing etc) so that the words are not cut / invisible in between** (maybe some other binarization technique which works on most of the cases or some parameter tuning)

I have this code to binarize / Threshold the image. It works fine on a wide range of images except a couple of things and the major problem being that it leads to loss of info due to some brightness and other factors. Some of the words are not readable or gets broken. Below is the code to threshold / Binarize along with some of the images. Also, [here is the link to 200 sample and resulting images](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xxDYSutn8VBKh7VI1w-x-tJxbpOKPiAx/view?usp=sharing)

```
import cv2
import skimage.filters as filters

def convert(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    smooth = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (103,103), 0)

    division = cv2.divide(gray, smooth, scale=255)

    sharp = filters.unsharp_mask(division, radius=1.5, amount=5, multichannel=False, preserve_range=False) # High Radius increase the density or surrounding pixels making it dense
    sharp = (255*sharp).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

    thresh = cv2.threshold(sharp, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU )[1] 
    return thresh
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: there exist no simple solutions. directly use neural networks (CNNs) on the raw grayscale/color data instead, to directly predict the letters. do not threshold. thresholding destroys data.

Comment: I could have used `UNET` or some other but in order to do that, I need to have the binarized data first. Isn't there any solution on the traditional CV?

Comment: In the image above, it is already blurred. Try removing the Gaussian Blur from the code or try using Global or Adaptive thresholding. I don't know if it will work or not but its worth a short.

Comment: If I remove the Gaussian Blur, it'll make other dark parts as visible. This is the only problem. If you look at the given 200 image samples, you'll see very poor quality images there so blur is must else the dark part will be too dark

Comment: This is not the answer you want; but may help :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/68949285/2227070

Answer (score 0):

You can test several types of histogram equalization techniques. I've scripted down two examples of histogram equalization with your above photo. You can than later keep preprocessing those raw results for better outcomes depending on your data variance.

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# read a image using imread
img = cv2.imread("test.png")
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# creating a Histograms Equalization
equ = cv2.equalizeHist(img_gray)
  
# clahe
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=10.0, tileGridSize=(100,100))
cl = clahe.apply(img_gray)
  
# show image input vs output
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(img)
plt.title("original image")
plt.show()  

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(equ, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.title("histogram equalization")
plt.show()  

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
plt.imshow(cl, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.title("CLAHE")
plt.show()
```

The results are:
[image: results for histogram equalization]

Comment: But there are lots of Parameters to tune and tuning these parameters is the only problem here due to a wide variety of image qualities. Can you just put of  the idea here so that I can test thoseaal/combanitions

Comment: For a single image, by tuning my algo's params, I can create a good quality but this is not the point. Tuning for All the images is the real point here. Some images are dark, some are very bright, Blur has it's own wide ranges, Noise etc. So your example works o one but not all.